# Cannot find control with name for last form control

Tags: angular, mat-form-field

I have a small project to display images on our nas.
I'm using angular 17.
On the main page I have 3 mat-form-fields. For some reason when I add the last of the tree mat-form-fields I get the error - ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'numberOfPicture'.

I discovered that no matter what type of input I add as the last input I get the same error when I add formControlName to the last input, be it a datepicker, regular text or select.

I have no clue to reproduce it in stackblitz or similar tools, sorry.

I have cleaned the code to only show how to reproduce the error.

gallery.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Startdatum</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startPicker" formControlName="startDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="startPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #startPicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Slutdatum</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDateValue" formControlName="endDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="endDateValue"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #endDateValue></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Antal bilder</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="numberOfPicture">
            <mat-option [value]="10">10</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="20">20</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="50">50</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="100">100</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="200">200</mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="300">300</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

gallery.component.ts I probably have to many imports and if that is what causes the problem, please let me know.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { dialogIndata } from '../model/dialogIndata';
import { image } from '../model/image';
import { PhotoalbumService } from '../services/photoalbum.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatButtonModule

  ],
  templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
  styleUrl: './gallery.component.css'
})
export class GalleryComponent {

  filterForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }


  get startDate() {
    return this.filterForm.get('startDate');
  }

  get endDate() {
    return this.filterForm.get('endDate');
  }

  get numberOfPicture() {
    return this.filterForm.get('numberOfPicture');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      startDate: [''],
      endDate: [''],
      numberOfPictures: ['']
    });


    console.log(this.startDate);
    console.log(this.endDate);
    console.log(this.numberOfPicture);
  }

}
```

I have tried this with och without the css.

the following is the complete console log. I know its not that easy to read but it is the best I can do.

```
Object { _pendingDirty: false, _hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator: false, _pendingTouched: false, _onCollectionChange: _onCollectionChange()
, _parent: {…}, pristine: true, touched: false, _onDisabledChange: [], _rawValidators: null, _composedValidatorFn: null, … }
gallery.component.ts:61:12
Object { _pendingDirty: false, _hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator: false, _pendingTouched: false, _onCollectionChange: _onCollectionChange()
, _parent: {…}, pristine: true, touched: false, _onDisabledChange: [], _rawValidators: null, _composedValidatorFn: null, … }
gallery.component.ts:62:12
null gallery.component.ts:63:12
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'numberOfPicture'
    Angular 12
    GalleryComponent_Template gallery.component.html:20
    Angular 54
    <anonymous> main.ts:9
core.mjs:11760:22
Angular is running in development mode. core.mjs:29972:16
Ignoring unsupported entryTypes: largest-contentful-paint. core.mjs:33893:17
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:4200/@vite/client
Source Map URL: client.mjs.map

[vite] connected. client:324:21
```

If you need more info I'll do what I can to give you more.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In your FormGroup (component), the control name is `numberOfPictures` (with "s") but in your HTML the formControlName: `numberOfPicture` (with**out** "s"), sounds like a typo error.

Comment: Thank you @YongShun. It was the typo error. I wish I could blame my dyslexia but I should have seen that. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue seems to be a typo in your form control name. In your form group, you've defined the control as `numberOfPictures`, but in your template, you're trying to access it using `numberOfPicture`. The names should match exactly.
So your html should look like :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Antal bilder</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="numberOfPictures"> <!-- Corrected the control name here -->
        <mat-option [value]="10">10</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="20">20</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="50">50</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="100">100</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="200">200</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="300">300</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also in your typescript you have to change the function:

```
get numberOfPicture() {
    return this.filterForm.get('numberOfPictures');
  }
```

I hope that will help you.